# Unity 3d c# script wont change text in textmeshpro

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas

[image]

It seems to be an easy one but I've tried everything, digging through documentation, forms or YouTube tutorials doesn't make any difference. I've trying everything.

```cs
//someofcode
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using RDG;
using TMPro;

...
public TMPro.TMP_Text textnazwaobiektu;
public TMPro.TMP_Text textlevelobiektu;
public TMPro.TMP_Text textzarobekobiekku;

// of course before that is void update with some ifs but even if added this code without ifs doesn't work so it is not the case.

textlevelobiektu.text=statystykimebla.rzadkoscprzedmiotu.ToString();
//
textnazwaobiektu.text=statystykimebla.nazwaobiektu;
//statystykimebla.nazwaobiektu
textzarobekobiekku.text=((statystykimebla.rzadkoscprzedmiotu)*100).ToString()+"$/min";
...
```

This is what I've came up with after digging and doesn't seem to work. Text doesn't even move or change.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the correct text instances? Could you post your actual code? Current snippet wouldn't compile and it's hard to tell what could be wrong this way .. we know that the API of `TMP_Text.text` itself works as expected ... so it is something else ;)

Comment: here is full code https://pastebin.com/G65Bccaz

Comment: Well you see ... there is a couple of conditions that all can fail ... have you actually debugged if your inner code blocks are ever reached t all? Are you sure the tag is correct? Rather use `CompareTag` instead of `tag ==` it at least throws an error if the tag is wrong/doesn't exist.

Comment: code works cuz for example line Vibration.Vibrate(25, 200); does vibrate the phone

Comment: As a general hint for your coding live: Code in English!  It is **the** global communication and programming language and makes it easier for international people to help you since currently it is hard to understand what all your fields and things that happen actually mean ;)

Comment: Vibration.Vibrate does happen at least 4 times in your code though ... how do you know which exactly is the line getting called? Use proper debugging - minimum at some Debug.Log and use breakpoints

Comment: yea sorry project is just for me to learn and actually do a free game on google play.

Comment: yes but this function of code adds vector on y axis so im sure it works because object is changing its position on y

Comment: and you are sure the values of `statystykimebla` are ever changed? And you don't get any errors right?

Comment: DerHugo!!! URE MASTER the problem was not the text but just that code. after deleting lines with statystykimebla textchange works! Im closing and thank u very much! U've saved me a lot of head scrachin

Answer (score -1):

Try and use `TextMeshProUGUI` instead of `TMPro.TMP_Text`, like this:

```
public TextMeshProUGUI textnazwaobiektu;
public TextMeshProUGUI textlevelobiektu;
public TextMeshProUGUI textzarobekobiekku;
```

Also make sure that the lines that updates the text are executed. Try use debugging.

Comment: changing it to textmeshprougui doesnt make any diffrence, Im pretty sure that it is executed because it is inside of working code. And also I tried to take out it of it so it runs without any ifs and still doesnt work

Comment: wouldn't make any difference since `TextMeshProUGUI` inherits from and therefore **IS** a `TMP_Text`